# Xpages: is it possible to set something in a theme so that a resource (like css or SSJS or CSJS) is applied to every Xpage /CC in an app

Tags: themes, xpages

I have a background gradient that I want to apply to every body tag in all the Xpages in databases that are inherited from this design.

I put the css resource in my template, and modified the theme so that this resource is included in every db that inherits from this template:

```
<resource>
  <content-type>text/css</content-type>
  <href>cc_CommonBackgroundGradient.css</href>
</resource>
```

Is it possible to set something so that every Xpage in an application will automatically include a set of resources, besides the somewhat obvious one of making a CC that only includes these resources and include it on every Xpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One aspect to bear in mind is that the theme is only applied in the Render Response phase. So if you include an SSJS library, you won't be able to use it in `beforePageLoad` or `afterPageLoad`.

A theme is very useful for applying settings default or overridden properties to a specific type of component, e.g. a different open/close image to all sections, a default `pageName` property on the ViewRoot component (so top-level XPage properties). In terms of adding resources. So the ViewRoot is the control name you need in a theme for the body.

In terms of adding resources etc, unless I'm using `"#{javascript:...}` to compute settings, I'm not concerned about putting them in a theme rather than a custom control. I usually have a layout custom control. SSJS computed dynamically will only run once per page load / refresh in a theme (just in Render Response), compared to every phase of the lifecycle in a custom control. If it's hard-coded, as in your example, the custom control is as good a place as any.